# CLI plugin installation problem on Grafana

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, grafana

I'm getting the following error when trying to install a plugin from the Grafana CLI installed on Kubernetes. I deleted and rebuilt the pod, it works fine but the error persists. Other Grafana features are working fine. What can I do?

`Failed to send requesterrorGet "https://grafana.com/api/plugins/repo": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)Error: ✗ Failed to send request: Get "https://grafana.com/api/plugins/repo": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say there is no problem with Grafana working. Kubernetes also does not give an error with the pod. In the error content, it says "Failed to send request: Get". Most likely it can access the internet but not dns resolution. If ping 8.8.8.8 is working but ping google.com is not working, you need to add nameserver.

For this, you can add something like the following into the /etc/resolv.conf file.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right on this, Its worked after I edit resolv.conf. Thanks